# Parsing and evaluating equations with inequalities in Python using sympy causing a SyntaxError

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, lambdify, parse_expr
from sympy.core.relational import Relational

# Define symbolic variables
x1, x2 = symbols('x1 x2')

# List of equations or inequalities that serve as constraints in the two-dimensional linear system
sel = ["2 * X1 + 1 * X2 >= 2", "3 * X1 + 4 * X2 <= 12", "4 * X1 + 3 * X2 <= 12"]
sel = ["2 * X1 + 1 * X2 >= 2", "3 * X1 + 4 * X2 == 12", "4 * X1 + 3 * X2 <= 12"]
sel = ["2 * X1 + 1 * X2 >= 2", "3 * X1 + 4 * X2 <= 12", "4 * X1 + 3 * X2 <= 12", "X1 + X2 - 4 == 0"]


# Linear constraints (inequalities)
linear_constraints = []
# Linear constraints (equations)
equations = []

# Separate the inequalities from the equations
for equation in sel:
    parsed_eq = equation.replace('X1', 'x1').replace('X2', 'x2')
    if '>=' in parsed_eq or '<=' in parsed_eq:
        linear_constraints.append(Relational(parse_expr(parsed_eq), 0))
    else:
        equations.append(parse_expr(parsed_eq))

# Define the range of values for the x-axis
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)

# List to store the intersection points
intersections = []

# Solve the inequalities and find the intersections
for constraint in linear_constraints:
    if isinstance(constraint, Relational):
        inequality = constraint.rel_op

        if inequality == '>=':
            r = solve(Eq(constraint.lhs - constraint.rhs, 0), x2)[0]
        elif inequality == '<=':
            r = solve(Eq(constraint.lhs - constraint.rhs, 0), x2)[0]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid inequality sign")

        intersections.append((0, r.subs(x1, 0)))
        intersections.append((solve(Eq(constraint.lhs - constraint.rhs, 0), x1)[0].subs(x2, 0), 0))
    else:
        r = solve(Eq(constraint, 0), x2)[0]
        intersections.append((0, r.subs(x1, 0)))
        intersections.append((solve(Eq(constraint, 0), x1)[0].subs(x2, 0), 0))

# Solve the equations and find the intersections
for equation in equations:
    r = solve(equation, (x1, x2))
    for solution in r:
        intersections.append((solution[x1], solution[x2]))

# Filter the points that are in the first quadrant
vertices = [point for point in intersections if point[0] >= 0 and point[1] >= 0]

# Print the vertices
for i, vertex in enumerate(vertices):
    print(f"Vertex {i+1}: {vertex}")

# Retrieve the x and y coordinates of the vertices
x_coords = [vertex[0] for vertex in vertices]
y_coords = [vertex[1] for vertex in vertices]

# Plot the vertices
plt.plot(x_coords, y_coords, 'ro')

# Traverse the list of equations, calculate the constraints, and plot them
for equation in sel:
    # Parse the equation and obtain the inequality
    parsed_eq = equation.replace('X1', 'x1').replace('X2', 'x2')
    inequality = parsed_eq.split()[1]

    # Solve the equation to obtain the linear constraint
    if inequality == '>=':
        r = solve(Eq(parse_expr(parsed_eq.replace('=', '-'))), x2)[0]
    elif inequality == '<=':
        r = solve(Eq(parse_expr(parsed_eq.replace('=', '-'))), x2)[0]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid inequality sign")

    # Create the linear constraint function
    linear_constraint = lambdify(x1, r, 'numpy')

    # Evaluate the linear constraint in the range of x
    y = linear_constraint(x)

    # Plot the linear constraint
    plt.plot(x, y, label=equation)

# Adjust the plot limits
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)

# Each constraint is plotted using plt.plot() with a specific label obtained from the list of equations.
# The plt.legend() function takes those labels and displays them in the plot as a legend that identifies each constraint.
plt.legend()

# Show the axis labels
plt.xlabel('x1')
plt.ylabel('x2')

# Set ticks in increments of 1 unit
plt.xticks(np.arange(-10, 11, 1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-10, 11, 1))

plt.title('Constraint Graph')
plt.axhline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
plt.axvline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)
plt.grid(True, linestyle='--', alpha=0.7)

# Show the resulting plot
plt.show()
```

I am trying to parse and evaluate equations with inequalities using the sympy library in Python. However, when I include equations along with inequalities in the `sel` list, I encounter a `SyntaxError`. The error message I receive is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_sel.py", line 26, in <module>
    equations.append(Eq(parse_expr(parsed_eq), 0))
    expr = eval(
  File "<string>", line 1
    Symbol ('x1' )+Symbol ('x2' )-Integer (4 )=Integer (0 )
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think the error is caused by using eval to parse and evaluate the equation in the line `expr = eval(equation.replace('X1', 'x1').replace('X2', 'x2'))`.

Why this error is happening? And how to solve it?

If I replace = with == I get this error:

```
  File "plot_sel.py", line 49, in <module>
    r = solve(Eq(constraint, 0), x2)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The `^` points to the `=`.  Review `sympys` gotchas regarding `=`, `==`  and Eq`

Comment: @hpaulj In list `sel = ["2 * X1 + 1 * X2 >= 2", "3 * X1 + 4 * X2 <= 12", "4 * X1 + 3 * X2 <= 12", "X1 + X2 - 4 = 0"]` I have not put any power symbol `^`, and regarding the equal signs, do you think I should change `=` to `==` ?

Comment: @hpaulj is not saying you have a "^" in your equation, they're referring to the error message which is telling you the issue is with `=`. When writing an equation in sympy, you need to use `==` instead of a single `=`.

Comment: @jared I tried but it didn't work... :(

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Did you get the same error? A different error?

Comment: @jared Same error     `expr = eval(  File "<string>", line 1
    Symbol ('x1' )+Symbol ('x2' )-Integer (4 )=Integer (0 )^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I still see a `=`.  Also your 3 `sel` lines don't make a list.

Comment: While learning sympy it would be a good idea to write the constraint expressions directly rather than parsing a string.  You should get better feedback about problems like this.  I like to test sympy in an interactive session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a single `=` sign does not work when using sympy's `Eq` function, you need to use a `==`. On top of that, the `Eq` function takes two arguments, which are the expressions on either side of the `==`. So, you need to split the string at the `==` as shown below. I also made use of the `local_dict` argument for `parse_expr`, so you don't need to use the string replace method.

```py
for equation in sel:
    variables = {"X1":x1, "X2":x2}
    # inequality code
    else:
        split_eq = equation.split("==")
        parsed_eq = [parse_expr(eq, local_dict=variables) for eq in split_eq] 
        equations.append(Eq(*parsed_eq))
```

Also, I assume you did not intend to evaluate your inequalities. You probably wanted to keep them as inequalities. Like with the `==`, you need to split the equations on the inequality signs and pass each part separately along with the inequality sign.

```py
for equation in sel:
    variables = {"X1":x1, "X2":x2}
    if ">=" in equation:
        split_eq = equation.split(">=")
        parsed_eq = [parse_expr(eq, local_dict=variables) for eq in split_eq] 
        linear_constraints.append(Relational(*parsed_eq, ">="))
    elif "<=" in equation:
        split_eq = equation.split("<=")
        parsed_eq = [parse_expr(eq, local_dict=variables) for eq in split_eq] 
        linear_constraints.append(Relational(*parsed_eq, "<="))
    elif "==" in equation:
        split_eq = equation.split("==")
        parsed_eq = [parse_expr(eq, local_dict=variables) for eq in split_eq] 
        equations.append(Eq(*parsed_eq))
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown symbol in equation: {equation}.")
```

Now, you can use the `solve` function directly on both the linear constraints and equations.

Comment: You can also use `Eq` in the string e.g. `parse_expr('Eq(x, y)')`.

Answer (score 1):

Test these `sel` lists in a ipython session with `x1,x2` symbols defined.

```
sel = [2 * x1 + 1 * x2 >= 2, 3 * x1 + 4 * x2 = 12, 4 * x1 + 3 * x2 <= 12]
  Cell In[10], line 1
    sel = [2 * x1 + 1 * x2 >= 2, 3 * x1 + 4 * x2 = 12, 4 * x1 + 3 * x2 <= 12]
                                 ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to expression here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?
```

More clearly than your version, this tells us the problem with the `=`.

But if I use `==`:

```
sel = [2 * x1 + 1 * x2 >= 2, 3 * x1 + 4 * x2 == 12, 4 * x1 + 3 * x2 <= 12]

type(sel[0])
Out[12]: sympy.core.relational.GreaterThan

type(sel[1])
Out[13]: bool

type(sel[2])
Out[14]: sympy.core.relational.LessThan

sel
Out[15]: [2*x1 + x2 >= 2, False, 4*x1 + 3*x2 <= 12]
```

The second equality did not give a relational. But using sympy `Eq` instead:

```
In [21]: sel = [2 * x1 + 1 * x2 >= 2, sp.Eq(3 * x1 + 4 * x2, 12), 4 * x1 + 3 * x2 <= 12]

In [22]: sel
Out[22]: [2*x1 + x2 >= 2, Eq(3*x1 + 4*x2, 12), 4*x1 + 3*x2 <= 12]

In [23]: type(sel[1])
Out[23]: sympy.core.relational.Equality
```

The problem with **=** is front and center on this page https://docs.sympy.org/latest/explanation/gotchas.html

You do use `Eq` later in the code!

Comment: If I replace = with == I get this error now line 49, in <module>   r = solve(Eq(constraint, 0), x2)[0] IndexError: list index out of range